# The proper way to initialize a list struct with resizable array

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, malloc

I have an initialization for a struct that I keep getting a `segmentation fault: 11` for.

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    double value;
    char* name;
} Item;

typedef struct {
    Item** items;
    int length;
    int capacity;
} List;

List* initList()
{
    List* list = NULL;
    list->items = (Item**)malloc(10 * sizeof(Item*));
    list->length = 0;
    list->capacity = 10;
    return list;
}
```

Here in `main.c` is where I get an error per GDB:

```
List* list = initList();
```

I cannot initialize, I notice because there is a problem with

```
list->items = (Item**)malloc(10 * sizeof(Item*));
```

I am new to C, but I am sure that my `initList` function will create a list with the given assignments. I also have a respective function to free the `items` in `initList`.

Comment: `List* list = NULL;` you don't allocate a `List` structure, but you're filling it in the next line. Undefined behaviour.

Comment: `List* list = NULL;
    list->items = ...`. You are dereferencing `list` which is NULL.

Comment: After stating `List* list = NULL;` the next line `list->items = ...` is derefencing a `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
List* list = NULL;
list->items = (Item**)malloc(10 * sizeof(Item*));
```

You initialize `list` with a `NULL` value, then you dereference `list` without giving it another value.  Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory for `list`.  Then you can dereference it:

```
List* list = malloc(sizeof(List *));
if (!list) {
    perror("malloc failed");
    exit(1);
}
list->items = malloc(10 * sizeof(Item*));
if (!list->items) {
    perror("malloc failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

Also, note that [you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and don't forget to check for errors.

Comment: Always so quick.

Answer (score 1):

in

```
list->items = (Item**)malloc(10 * sizeof(Item*));
```

the right hand side isn't the issue. The issue is that because `list` points to `NULL`, assigning something to one of it's field is *undefined behaviour*.

You could avoid this allocation, by returning a structure instead of a pointer. No need to allocate the structure dynamically, it has a fixed size.

```
List initList()
{
    List list;
    list.items = malloc(10 * sizeof(Item*));
    list.length = 0;
    list.capacity = 10;
    return list;
}
```

caller:

```
List list = initList();
```

the copy overhead is very small, but the benefits of not carrying another dynamically allocated pointer for nothing is big.

Comment: Is `List list = NULL;` legal? I've always used `memset`